# Requirejs issue in OroCRM 4.1

Tags: requirejs, orocrm

I have installed OroCRM 4.1 version.The requirejs bundle doesn't seem to have loaded. I checked the bundles folder and i do not see the ororequirejs folder there, which was present in the previous version (4.0). Because of this the custom extension i have that uses require to include js files are failing. I tried `php bin/console oro:requirejs:build` command but its failing with the messsage *There are no commands defined in the "oro:requirejs" namespace.* Can someone help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

RequireJsBundle is not available in OroCRM 4.1, as an application migrated to the webpack build.

Please, follow the migration guide referenced from CHANGELOG.md:
https://github.com/oroinc/platform/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#requirejsbundle